# What is the significance of the emitted event.point.index from mousing over a chart?

Tags: anychart

I am trying to determine the nearest x value of the user's mouse position on a simple line chart. Is there any way to do this?

I have already tried adding a pointMouseOver and pointsHover listener to the chart instance, and, while they emit some kind of index, the number of indices far exceeds the number of x values in the chart (My chart had around 600 x values, the largest index emitted is around 1000).

```
this.chart.listen('pointMouseOver', function (event) {
                        console.log(event.iterator.getIndex())
                        console.log(event)
                    })
```

returns some arbitrary index instead of the nearest x value.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my question myself while looking through the charts API reference - to get the nearest x value on pointsHover, call event.point.get('x'). https://playground.anychart.com/api/_samples/anychart.enums.EventType.pointsHover